# I am trying to make a drawImage change when mouseover and mouseout

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouse, mouseover, mouseout

I'm attempting to make it, so that when the mouse is within the boundaries set by var play, it changes image. I used the same method I've used for changing images on click, but mouseover and mouseout don't want to work here.

```
var play = {
    x: 650,
    y: 360,
    width: 200,
    height: 100
}
var playUpButton = new Image();
playUpButton.src = "images/PlayUp.png";
var playDownButton = new Image();
playDownButton.src = "images/PlayDown.png";
var playHovering = false;

thisCanvas.addEventListener('click', checkPlay);
thisCanvas.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverPlay, false);
thisCanvas.addEventListener('mouseout', hoverPlay, false);

function seen_move(e)
{
    var bounding_box = thisCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouseX = ((e.clientX-bounding_box.left) *(thisCanvas.width/bounding_box.width));
    mouseY = ((e.clientY-bounding_box.top) * (thisCanvas.height/bounding_box.height));
}

function draw_start()
{
    context.drawImage(menubg, menubg.x, menubg.y, menubg.width, menubg.height);
    if(playHovering)
    {
        context.drawImage(playDownButton, play.x, play.y, play.width, play.height);
    }
}


function mouseInArea(top, right, bottom, left)
{
    if(mouseX >= left && mouseX < right && mouseY >= top && mouseY < bottom)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}   

function hoverPlay()
{
    if(mouseInArea(play.y, play.x + play.width, play.y + play.height, play.x))
    {
        console.log("Hovering");
        if(playHovering)
        {
            playHovering = false;
        }
        else
        {
            playHovering = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following is missing from your code.

```
var thisCanvas = document.getElementById("thisCanvas");
```

The function checkPlay also seems to be missing.

Take a look at these articles:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1903884&seqNum=6

Comment: I didn't add all code. Sorry for the confusion, both those things are there.

Comment: Add some console.log statements into the hoverPlay function. It's hard to tell without all the code, but it's possible that the seen_move() function is never getting called.

Answer (score 0):

You must call `function seen_move(e)` to get the mouse position.

BTW, I'm confused about what the extra code in `seen_move` is. I'm guessing you're making the mouse position relative to the bounding box. I just mention it in case that's also a problem:

```
// this usually get the mouse position
var bounding_box = thisCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
mouseX = e.clientX-bounding_box.left;
mouseY = e.clientY-bounding_box.top;

// and you have this extra bit:
// *(thisCanvas.width/bounding_box.width)); and 
// * (thisCanvas.height/bounding_box.height));
mouseX = ((e.clientX-bounding_box.left) *(thisCanvas.width/bounding_box.width));
mouseY = ((e.clientY-bounding_box.top) * (thisCanvas.height/bounding_box.height));
```